# guest paypal checkout by using credit card payment without login in html form

Tags: paypal

I have created code below which contains a form in order to checkout paypal.

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-9UB86200PA2976623" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick"><input type="hidden" name="business" value="seller@designerfotos.com"><input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Memorex 256MB Memory Stick"><input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="MEM32507725"><input type="hidden" name="amount" value="3"><input type="hidden" name="tax" value="1"><input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1"><input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD"><input type="hidden" name="SOLUTIONTYPE" value="=Sole"><input type="hidden" name="LANDINGPAGE" value="=Billing"><!-- Enable override of buyers's address stored with PayPal . --><input type="hidden" name="address_override" value="1"><!-- Set variables that override the address stored with PayPal. --><input type="hidden" name="first_name" value="John"><input type="hidden" name="last_name" value="Doe"><input type="hidden" name="address1" value="345 Lark Ave"><input type="hidden" name="city" value="San Jose"><input type="hidden" name="state" value="CA"><input type="hidden" name="zip" value="95121"><input type="hidden" name="country" value="US"><input type="image" name="submit" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online"></form>
```

However, I am getting the following errors:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your code is invalid. The Express Checkout should be done from API. There are no such code in html yet can be implemented for Express Checkout.